# Linux grep or find usage

Tags: linux, grep

How do I find a file on my harddisk that starts with `io_file`?

I tried:

```
grep -r io_file*`
```

and

```
find -name io_file*
```

`find` did not return anything whereas `grep` seems to take ages without any results.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: grep and find are not intended for the same thing.

Comment: (not the same Tom as the poster)

Comment: With all due respect to the true find wizardry shown in the other answers, an alternative is to install [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/). This is a Perl tool that has a simpler interface and encompasses both find's and grep's major functionalities.

Answer (score 11):

`find / -name 'io_file*'`

The first parameter will specify where the search should start. `/` means your entire hard drive. To search in only the current directory (and subdirectories), use: `find .`

The search string must be quoted if it contains a shell metacharacter, such as an asterisk. Otherwise, it will be parsed by the shell and never seen by `find`.

Comment: Not entirely true. The search string will only be expanded **if there is a match**, otherwise it is left unexpanded. Try "echo thisisnotafile*", for example.

Comment: Jesper: is that shell-dependent behavior? The terminal I'm working from uses tcsh, and quoting makes a difference even for filenames which aren't expandable.

Comment: Thanks for that. And how can I say that I wanna look in the current directory AS WELL AS all subdirectories?

Comment: Just change the '/' for '.' (without quotes) (Again, not the poster)

Comment: @John Millikin: indeed, bash and tcsh have a different behavior.

Answer (score 7):

```
find / -name 'io_file*' -type f 2>/dev/null



   /: Start looking from root directory

   -type f: Only search for regular files

    2>/dev/null: Redirect errors to /dev/null. (handy if you are not root and
                 not interested in all the "access denied" messages)
```

Keep in mind that grep and find do different things.

> [grep](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep)  searches the named input FILEs
>   (or standard input if no files are
>          named, or the file name - is given) for lines containing a match to
>   the
>          given PATTERN.  By default, grep prints the matching lines.
>
> [find](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find) - search for files in a directory
>   hierarchy

Comment: -name pattern
      Don't forget
       to  enclose  the pattern  in quotes in order to protect it from
       expansion by the shell.

Comment: thats from the find man page

Comment: @jcolebrand nope

Answer (score 4):

IMO, using find is slow for an entire harddrive search (it will also show you a lot of permission errors when accessing files you do not own). If possible, use locate:

```
locate -b 'io_file*'
```

You'll probably have to re-index if the file is newer than 24h (normally it sets a daily cronjob):

```
sudo updatedb
```

Answer (score 2):

```
find / -name 'io_file*'
```

Answer (score 2):

The command

```
# set -x
```

will print commands after shell expansion so you can see what is going on

```
# find . -name letter.*
+ find . -name letter.rtf
```

...and now you can see that the shell is expanding the argument to name into `letter.rtf`, as my current driectory contains a file called `letter.rtf` that matches the pattern.

Quoting the pattern (double quotes work in this case also) will stop the shell expansion

```
# find . -name 'letter.*'
+ find . -name 'letter.*'
```

To turn it off, use

```
# set +x
```

You can also use `-x` on a [shebang line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) to see what shell scripts are doing which can greatly aid debugging.

```
#!/bin/bash -x
```

Answer (score 0):

The shell expands the wildcards and passes the result to grep, so you need to either escape the `*` or use quotes:

```
find / -name io_file\*
find / -name 'io_file*'
find / -name "io_file*"
```

All three of these do the same thing on my Linux box.

Answer (score 0):

`find -name io_file*` will search in the current directory and below only. If you want to search the entire harddrive, you need to specify the path: `find / -name io_file*`. Same thing goes with `grep -r`; it will only search in the current directory and below.

The `find` utility is very handy, but it may be a little counterintuitive to use. My recommendation is that you read the find man-page (`man find`), it is well worth the invested time.

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't give *grep* a file, it is operating on standard input and waiting for you to type something.  It's the wrong command anyway.  As for *find* you need a directory to start from and have to put `io_file*` in quotation marks, otherwise it gets expanded by the shell:

```
find / -name "io_file*"
```

You can also use `locate "io_file*"` which is faster but may be inaccurate.